# How do I enable desktop horizontal scrolling on windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have 4 applications windows beside each other.  The 4th one is off the screen. I want to be able to scroll across desktop.

Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK you'll need dual monitors. I doubt there's a program for that but I might be wrong.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=windows+7+scroll+desktop+horizontally&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr) gives a considerable amount of good looking hits..

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the size of the screen resolution and use the magnifier in zoom mode. I don't know how well that would work - but it's an option.

Be aware that it would increase the size horizontally as well, so that might cause more problems than fix.

Comment: Also, if you are just wanting to flip full-screen windows - don't forget about Alt-Tab and Windows-Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Would multiple desktops help? I've yet to see a tool adding them to Windows that hasn't seemed a bit buggy, but lately [Microsoft has been publishing one called Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) that sounds promising. [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) also seems to be pretty popular.